# Getting the probability of detection from Steganalysis tests

Tags: image-processing, probability, steganography

Reading this paper http://airccj.org/CSCP/vol5/csit53210.pdf and more specifically in section 8.1 he used Weighted Stego Steganalysis on his proposed method image vs LSB image to produce a chart to compare the probability of detection.

From my understanding the WS outputs the string estimation (p hat) my question is how did he derive such chart?

In other words, how he used P='Estimation of payload' to derive probability of detection chart?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I assume you're referring to figures 7 and 8. What exactly are you asking here? Are you asking for code that does the necessary calculations to output such a graph? If you want to understand the maths/rationale behind this and not writing an algorithm to do so, a different Stackexchange site is probably more appropriate. Why is matlab in your tags? Have you followed reference 24?

Comment: Probably shouldn't put Matlab there, I removed it.  Not asking for the code but how he used the output of the WS to produce a probability of detection(Figure 7 and 8 ). The WS produces P hat, which is an estimation of the payload.